# How to make Order By faster in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have two tables users and transactions. The users table contains UserId and UserName columns, the transactions table contains TransactionId, Amount(decimal) and UserId columns.
When I run the following query, it doesn't stop even after 10 minutes:

```
SELECT u.UserName,
       (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t.Amount), 0.0)
        FROM Transactions AS t
        WHERE t.UserId = u.UserId) AS `Sum`
FROM Users as u
ORDER BY Sum
LIMIT 10
```

Without Order By it works in less than 1 second. I can't use group by. How should I write this to make it work faster.

When I fetch all data without Order By and sort them by Sum in the IDE, it works in less than 1 second. Why MySql doesn't work like in IDE. (I'm using JetBrains DataGrip)

Comment: Have you tried adding a GROUP BY or ORDER BY Sum ASC or DESC?

Comment: @ErisCacigieri - `ASC` is the default. `DESC` won't make any difference; in either case, one row per user is needed leading into the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Why can't you use GROUP BY? Is this just an exercise?

Answer (score 1):

**Plan A -- turn it inside out.**

```
SELECT  u.UserName, x.Sum
    FROM  
        ( SELECT  t.UserId,
                  COALESCE(SUM(t.Amount), 0.0) AS Sum
            FROM  Transactions AS t
            GROUP BY  t.UserId
            ORDER BY  Sum
            LIMIT  10 
        ) AS x
    JOIN  Users AS u  ON u.UserId = x.UserId
```

Suggested index:

```
t:  INDEX(UserId,  Amount)
```

This should be faster because of only looking at 1 table for the subquery, then needing only 10 lookups in the other table.

**Plan B -- Summary Table:**

You have many millions of rows?  Then I suggest you build and maintain a [*Summary Table*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) that contains the subtotal (`SUM`) for each day.  Then sum up the sums to get the grand totals very efficiently.  That way, subquery (in either formulation) will run much faster.

In case my suggestion does not help much, please tell us about how many distinct users there are and how many transactions there are.  And how many transactions per user per day.  (It may be that summarizing by week would be better.)

**Why ORDER BY mattered**

Without the `ORDER BY`, only 10 users are looked up.  (not the 10 you want)  The `ORDER BY` is, of course, necessary to find the 10 with the smallest totals.